# SQL Server: database altered

Tags: sql, sql-server

Somehow my database has disappeared from SQL Server. When I check the default trace, I found that it was altered. Can I get what alter statement was used from this trace?

Comment: Are you able to connect that database?

Comment: [Maybe](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-default-trace-in-sql-server-the-power-of-performance-and-security-auditing/).

Comment: No,I cant connect